# Final pricing jQuery script

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form which has three select options as follows:

```html
<select class="form-control" id="someId">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option id="10" value="option1">1</option>
  <option id="20" value="option2">2</option>
  <option id="30" value="option3">3</option>
  <option id="40" value="option4">4</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="someId">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option id="10" value="option1">1</option>
  <option id="20" value="option2">2</option>
  <option id="30" value="option3">3</option>
  <option id="40" value="option4">4</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="someId">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option id="10" value="option1">1</option>
  <option id="20" value="option2">2</option>
  <option id="30" value="option3">3</option>
  <option id="40" value="option4">4</option>
</select>
```

Each option id corresponding to a price, how would I get the prices of the option selected and add it up with the price of another option selected, then output it as a final price in jQuery?  My main enquiry is how to get the prices in jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go with ids, you can write a simple script with jQuery. *Code explained in comments*

```js
$('select').on('change', function() { // Handle select on change event
  var price1 = parseInt($("#price1").val()); // Get the numerical values
  var price2 = parseInt($("#price2").val());
  var price3 = parseInt($("#price3").val());
 
  var total = price1 + price2 + price3; // Calculate total
  if (isNaN(total)) {
    $('.final-price').text('Select other prices'); // When at least one of the select options is missing
  } else {
    $('.final-price').text('Total price: ' + total); // Display output
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="price1">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option id="10" value="10">1</option>
  <option id="20" value="20">2</option>
  <option id="30" value="30">3</option>
  <option id="40" value="40">4</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="price2">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option id="10" value="10">1</option>
  <option id="20" value="20">2</option>
  <option id="30" value="30">3</option>
  <option id="40" value="40">4</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="price3">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option id="10" value="10">1</option>
  <option id="20" value="20">2</option>
  <option id="30" value="30">3</option>
  <option id="40" value="40">4</option>
</select>
<div class="final-price"></div>
```

Comment: won't this `$("#price1").text()` return selected option's text ?

Comment: What you provided is more of what I am seeking, but how would you do this if the actual options were not the prices but had prices associated with them? I tried to use the ids to associate the price with them but perhaps I should use the values or a class, but even if I do how would I get the price associated with the option

Comment: You mean the value attribute contains the prices and the text contains the item names?

Comment: @ManojKumar yes, exactly.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi Thanks for the correction, I just realized he wanted to add the options values instead of the text inside. Code updated!

Answer (score 3):

Id must be unique you can't duplicate it

Try to use class instead of id

Like this

```
<select class="form-control" >
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="10" >1</option>
  <option value="20">2</option>
  <option value="30" selected>3</option>
  <option value="40" >4</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="10" >1</option>
  <option value="20">2</option>
  <option value="30" selected>3</option>
  <option value="40">4</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="10" >1</option>
  <option value="20">2</option>
  <option value="30" selected>3</option>
  <option value="40" >4</option>
</select>
```

Then try

```
var sum=0;
$('select.form-control').each(function(){
   sum+=  +$(this).val();
});
console.log(sum);
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/p4re857j/)**